# How to enable executing php files in Fedora Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, httpd, fedora

I installed `httpd` and php `v8.2.11` on my Linux Fedora.

But Apache can't execute `.php` files. (Responses "Access denied.")

I tried to use `chmod` shell command to enable executing and add `AddType text/html .php .phps` in `httpd.conf` file and restarting `httpd.service` but it can't execute php scripts yet.

**NOTE**: I can execute `.html` files.

**NOTE**: I tried to set `chomd` of `php` files `777` (while I know it's very dangerous) but It still unable to execute.

Here is what I found in the error log:

```
AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /var/www/backend/index.php (Permission denied)'
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need "chmod 777" change your permission to:

```
chmod 644 /var/www/backend/index.php
```

Make sure the owner and group are set to the web server user (usually apache or www-data).

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/backend/index.php
```

Verify that the directory containing your PHP files has the correct permissions. The directory and its parent directories should be accessible by Apache.

```
chmod 755 /var/www/backend
```

If you are using SELinux on Fedora, it might enforce additional security policies. To check SELinux contexts and correct them, you can use the ls -Z command and the chcon command

```
ls -Z /var/www/backend
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/backend
```

Verify that your Apache configuration allows for PHP execution. In your Apache configuration file (httpd.conf or an included file), you should have the following lines

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Ensure that these lines are not commented out. Also, make sure your virtual host configuration (if you have one) includes the DirectoryIndex directive with "index.php."

Ensure that the PHP module is loaded by Apache. You can check if the php module is loaded using:

```
apachectl -M
```

After making changes to file permissions and configurations, restart Apache to apply the changes

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete help friend. Its all correct but `apachectl -M` command. I tried to execute this, but returns `Passing arguments to httpd using apachectl is no longer supported.
You can only start/stop/restart httpd using this script.`. However, my problem fixed.